# How to use substr() on php?

Tags: php

I am trying to get "pa" from "a(bcdefghijkl(mno)pa)q".
This is my code for exampe:

```
$s = "a(bcdefghijkl(mno)pa)q";
$mystring = substr($s,14,15);
echo $mystring;
```

outputs is:

```
mno)pa)q
```

Comment: What's the problem ?

Comment: Your range is wrong, also 3th parameter of `substr` is `length`. So you should use `substr($s,18,2)`

Comment: https://3v4l.org/XYZu7

Comment: thanks for answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***You have use right code but the second parameter is wrong. use this one below***

```
$s = "a(bcdefghijkl(mno)pa)q";
$mystring = substr($s,14,2);
echo $mystring;
```

In substr function:
first parameter means from which position of string starts.
and the second parameter means how many characters you have want.

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = "a(bcdefghijkl(mno)pa)q";
$mystring = substr($s,-4,2); 
echo $mystring;
```

Try this

Comment: Don't you think you should mention @Mohammad for giving the right answer in comment?

Comment: I did check the time he posted before you :)

Comment: I saw the comment when you said here :)